# is it possible to have the Recepisse extended for internship,10 months after giving the final exams?

Tags: france, student-visa, students, europe, internship

I came to France in 2017 September end for a 1-year masters course, however, couldn't find an internship until now, I gave an interview in a company and they told me they have a vacancy for an internship in the month of July, but I just renewed my recepisse with the letter provided by the college asking for an extension, however as I did not sign any contract yet, due to which I was only given  an extension until July and the lady at the prefecture told m this was my last recepisse for this course, but I really would like to know if I sign a convention de stage is there any way I Can  an extension from July until January so I can finish the internship?

P.s: (please find the letter of extension provided by my college in the attachment) I really do not wanna miss this internship opportunity any suggestion is much appreciated, Thanks In advance.

Comment: *please find the letter of extension provided by my college in the attachment* ???

Comment: There's no image / attachment @rahul thevar